# php artisan migrate:fresh --seed can't seed a table into MySQL

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-seeding, wamp64

I just started learning PHP and Laravel 7 with no prior experience. I think Artisan and I are having some trust issues and I don't know why. :) 
I reached the seeding step and I'm facing an error that I need your expertise to solve in an easy way. Below are the previous steps I did before facing this issue.

I create the product controller& model

`php artisan make:model Product -m -c -resource`

**Database**

```php
class CreateProductsTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name', 100);
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->string('type');
            $table->decimal('price', 2);
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
}
```

**Model**

```php
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'product';
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'image', 'type', 'price', 'description'];
}
```

**Controller**

```php
class ProductController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
       $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $product = DB::table('products')->get();
    }
}
```

**AppServiceProvider**

```php
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    }
}
```

After that, I created the **ProductTableSeeder**

> php artisan make:seeder ProductTableSeeder

```php
class ProductTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        Product::insert([
            'name' => 'iphone',
            'type' => 'smart phone',
            'price' => 1000.98,
            'description' => 'Cillum sint dolore sint labori',
        ]);

        Product::insert([
            'name' => 'Galaxy',
            'type' => 'tablets',
            'price' => 2000.50,
            'description' => 'Cillum sint dolore sint labori',
        ]);

        Product::insert([
            'name' => 'Sony',
            'type' => 'TV',
            'price' => 3000,
            'description' => 'Cillum sint dolore sint labori',
        ]);
    }
}
```

then, called the seeder

```php
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        // $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
        $this->call(ProductTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

Then, `composer dump-autoload`

Finally, after typing the seeding command

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

I keep getting the following error.

> ```
> Dropped all tables successfully.
> Migration table created successfully.
> Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
> Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (0.51 seconds)
> Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
> Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (0.12 seconds)
> Migrating: 2020_04_13_063011_create_products_table
> Migrated:  2020_04_13_063011_create_products_table (0.18 seconds)
> Seeding: ProductTableSeeder
>
>    Illuminate\Database\QueryException
>
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'e-commerce.product' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `product`
> ```
>
> (`name`, `type`, `price`, `description`) values (iphone, smart phone,
>   1000.98, Cillum sint dolore sint labori))
>
> ```
>   at C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:671
>     667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
>     668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
>     669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
>     670|         catch (Exception $e) {
>   > 671|             throw new QueryException(
>     672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
>     673|             );
>     674|         }
>     675|
>
>   • A table was not found: You might have forgotten to run your migrations. You can run your migrations using `php artisan migrate`.
>     https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#running-migrations
>
>   1   C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
>       PDOException::("SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'e-commerce.product' doesn't exist")
>
>   2   C:\wamp64\www\E-Commerce\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:458
>       PDO::prepare("insert into `product` (`name`, `type`, `price`, `description`) values (?, ?, ?, ?)")
> ```

Answer (score -1):

this answer from @Ersoy

> @kha you either remove `$table`
>
> property or modify it like
>
> ```
> protected $table = 'products';
> ```

helped me fix the issue and Here is the solution.

in the Model, I add 's' at the end of the table name (forgot to make it plural)

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'products'; //(forgot to make it plural)

    protected $fillable = ['name','image','type','price','description',
                          ];
}
```

The controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Product;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
       //$this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
         $prod = Product::paginate(20);
         return view('allproducts');

    // $products = [0=>['name'=>'iphone','category'=>'smart phone', 'price'=>1000,],
    //              1=>['name'=>'Galaxy','category'=>'tablets', 'price'=>2000],
    //              2=>['name'=>'Sony','category'=>'TV', 'price'=>3000]];
    // return $products;

     //return view('allproducts',compact('product'));
}
```

changed the price's variable from decimal to double

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();

        $table->string('name', 100);
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->string('type');
        $table->double('price', 2);//change the variable
        $table->text('description')->nullable();

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

then run the command

```
php artisan migrate:refresh --seed

Rolling back: 2020_04_13_063011_create_products_table
Rolled back:  2020_04_13_063011_create_products_table (0.08 seconds)
Rolling back: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Rolled back:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (0.06 seconds)
Rolling back: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Rolled back:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (0.1 seconds)
Rolling back: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Rolled back:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (0.08 seconds)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table (0.39 seconds)
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table (0.52 seconds)
Migrating: 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table
Migrated:  2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table (0.17 seconds)
Migrating: 2020_04_13_063011_create_products_table
Migrated:  2020_04_13_063011_create_products_table (0.12 seconds)
Seeding: ProductTableSeeder
Seeded:  ProductTableSeeder (0.02 seconds)
Database seeding completed successfully.
```

I guess artisan was right not trusting me from the beginning. :)